# Using parameters in ms excel filter function

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, excel-365

I need to select multiple values from a table whose size can vary. So currently i have hardcoded the range in the FILTER function. I need to parameterize the range. Any idea how it works?

I tried to keep the numerical value in a separate column and used & to call this, but its showing error. Please help.

I am using something like this currently,

```
=filter(sheet2!A1:J10,sheet2!C1:C10=sheet1!A2,”not found”)
```

Here, the number of records in Sheet2 can be variable. Currently it is 10. I took the `COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A)` in a “column L” in sheet 1 and tried to use it as parameter but didn’t work.

```
=filter(sheet2!A1:J&L1,sheet2!C1:C&L1=sheet1!A2,”not found”)
```

Comment: it would be useful to see an example of the sheet you are working with. I might use a data table  that way you don't need to hard code ranges

Comment: It would be best to put the data in a structured table. Then you could have something like `=FILTER(Table1,Table1[Title]=Sheet1!A2,"not found")`. Otherwise, to make your idea work, you need to use the volatile `INIDIRECT` i.e. `=FILTER(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A1:J"&L1),INDIRECT("Sheet2!C1:C"&L1)=Sheet1!A2,”not found”)`.

Comment: Just wondering. Would using `=filter(sheet2!A:J,sheet2!C:C=sheet1!A2,”not found”)` be less efficient than using the COUNTA() stored elsewhere, or inside LET? Otherwise that's better readable (apart from VBasics suggestion to use a table, which I think is the best option)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula:

```
=LET(d,Sheet2!A:J,
cntRows,COUNTA(CHOOSECOLS(d,1)),
data,TAKE(d,cntRows),
FILTER(data,INDEX(data,,3) = sheet1!A2, "not found"))
```

It stores the number of filled rows in `cntRows`, creates the used range in `data` and does the filtering

Comment: Instead of `sheet1!A2), "not found")` should be: `sheet1!A2, "not found"))`